# Why am I not getting any feedback as to whether my form is completed correctly or incorrectly? Python, Django

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I'm working in Django with Python, and here are is my views.py

```
def register(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        auth_login(request, user)
        print("success")
        return render(request, 'Upload.html', {})

        # messages.success(request, "Regisration successful.")
        # print("hello")
        return render(request, "Home.html")
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        return render(request, 'Register.html', {'form': form})

form = NewUserForm()
return render(request, 'Register.html', context={"form":form})
```

This is my HTML

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block css %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'website/Register.css' %} " media="screen">
    {% endblock %}


    {% block content %} 

<section class="u-align-center u-clearfix u-section-1" id="sec-6951">
  <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
    <div class="u-align-center u-form u-form-1">
      <form action="#" method="POST" class="u-clearfix u-form-spacing-10 u-form-vertical u-inner-form" source="custom" name="form" style="padding: 10px;">
        {% csrf_token %}
    

        <div class="u-form-email u-form-group">
          <label for="email-87f0" class="u-label">Email</label>
          <input type="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" id="email-87f0" name="email" class="u-border-1 u-border-grey-30 u-input u-input-rectangle u-white" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="u-form-group u-form-name">
          <label for="name-87f0" class="u-label">Username</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Create a username" id="name-87f0" 
           name="username" class="u-border-1 u-border-grey-30 u-input u-input-rectangle u-white" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="u-form-group u-form-name u-form-group-3">
          <label for="name-12e6" class="u-label">Password</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Create a password" id="name-12e6" name="password1" class="u-border-1 u-border-grey-30 u-input u-input-rectangle u-white" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="u-form-group u-form-name u-form-group-4">
          <label for="name-12e6" class="u-label">Verify Password</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Verify your password" id="name-12e6" name="password2" class="u-border-1 u-border-grey-30 u-input u-input-rectangle u-white" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="u-align-center u-form-group u-form-submit">
          <a href="#" class="u-btn u-btn-submit u-button-style">Create Account</a>
          <input type="submit" value="submit" class="u-form-control-hidden">
        </div>
       
          <ul class="messages">
              {{ messagez }} </li>
              {{ form.errors }}
      
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

    {% endblock %}}
```

The messagez and form.errors is an attempt of getting the code out on the HTML. I have no clue how I can get that code to appear on the HTML. I want it to say "Success" or display the form.error

Comment: Errors that are specific to a field won't be in `form.errors`, they will be in `form.fieldname.errors`.  Since you're rolling your own custom html for the form, you'll need to add this to each field in your form display.

Comment: Whenever I print the form error with print(form.errors) it works. I just want to pass that through to the HTML and display it. Are you saying that I can do that by changing {{ form.errors }} to {{form.fieldname.errors}}?

What do I have to alter when I roll my own custom HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using alert to display the error message to your intended template.

Perhaps this code in your Template could work.

```html
{% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            {{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

For more details, refer to the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a better, more correct time using a [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView) rather than implementing a form view as a function-based view.

```
class RegisterView(FormView):
    form_class = NewUserForm
    template_name = "Register.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        auth_login(self.request, user)
        return redirect("/")  # assuming that's the Home to redirect to
```

You'll also have a better time letting Django lay out your form – it will take care of printing errors, initial values, placeholders, etc. too:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

That default table layout will probably not look like what you want – a popular option to help with that is [`django-crispy-forms`](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I just let the built in Django framework take over and deleted my HTML. It's too hard to run my own stuff and I used crispy instead.